# como solucionar el error de java; com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, netbeans, xampp

Hola estoy tratando de actualizar los datos de una base de datos y para eso hice este codigo dentro del boton actualizar... y el error q sale es este(jul 10, 2020 12:08:49 AM Formularios.frmActualizar Btn_ActualizarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near .......line 1) espero y me puedan ayudar...Gracias.

```
Codigo:
```

try {

```
ConexionBD Con = new ConexionBD();
Con.ConectarBD();
String id = AtxtID.getText();
String td = AcbTD.getSelectedItem().toString();
String doc = AtxtDocumento.getText();
String nom = AtxtNombre.getText();
String ape = AtxtApellido.getText();
String tel = AtxtTelefono.getText();
String dir = AtxtDireccion.getText();
String fi = AtxtFechaI.getText();
String hi = AtxtHoraI.getText();
String mot = AtxtMotivo.getText();
String SQL = " UPDATE personas SET"
+ "Td = '"+td+"', Documento = '"+doc+"', Nombre = '"+nom+"',"
+ "Apellido = '"+ape+"', Telefono = '"+tel+"',"
+ "Direccion = '"+dir+"', Fecha_ing = '"+fi+"', Hora_ing = '"+hi+"',"
+ "Motivo = '"+mot+"'"
+ "WHERE Id = '"+id+"'";
Con.sentencia.execute(SQL);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Registro Actualizado con éxito!");
Con.DesconectarBD();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(frmActualizar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String SQL = "UPDATE personas SET"
+ " Td = '"+td+"', Documento = '"+doc+"', Nombre = '"+nom+"',"
+ "Apellido = '"+ape+"', Telefono = '"+tel+"',"
+ "Direccion = '"+dir+"', Fecha_ing = '"+fi+"', Hora_ing = '"+hi+"',"
+ "Motivo = '"+mot+"'"
+ " WHERE Id = '"+id+"'";
```

Te faltaba un espacio despues de SET y antes de Where